# Is this sentence idiomatic: "It works best the earliest it is given."

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

A doctor tells about adrenaline pens on TV. He says:

**"It works best the earliest it is given."** [ITV-Adrenaline pens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ha9STc_c0pE) (see:8:26-8:30)

As far as I understand, he means **"The earlier it is given, the better it works."** However, his sentence sounds unusual to me for some reason. Google search produces no results for this sentence.

It might be because two superlatives **"....best the earliest ...."** are used one after the other. Or maybe because I have not come across it before.

Really, is this an idiomatic usage?

Comment: check spelling.  Is "eartliest"  meant to be "earliest"?

Comment: I would regard this as a slip of the tongue. I daresay none of use have tried live TV presenting. It would be idiomatic if it had 'earlier' and not 'earliest': Alzheimer's Society UK (blog) _New results released in July 2023 showed that donanemab works better the earlier it is given._ A pretty common observation made about medications. (They work better if they are given before the illness has progressed significantly). Google will you you a bunch. E.g. _[Covid] antiviral Veklury performs better the earlier it is provided in both patients with severe and mild-to-moderate cases of the virus._

Comment: Not every conversation can serve as a model of language, even when it's easily understood. This example is just fine, from a well-spoken doctor, but not so ideal as to copy.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - 'earliest' is definitely wrong. It should be 'earlier',  and the result would a very normal and copiable expression.

Answer (score -1):

It is not idiomatic, the doctor is most likely not a native English speaker.

ETA: This assumption based on the use of the word "earliest", which is a grammatical error that most native speakers would not make.

Comment: So, no, it's not idiomatic, but there's no reason to make assumptions about the speaker's fluency. And without the unwarranted guess, there's not much to this answer; consider expanding it.

Comment: @AndyBonner - clarified!